# Python - How to run parallel processing queries from a list

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I've the following list of queries:

```
queries = ["SELECT * FROM db.trans", "SELECT * FROM db.order", "SELECT * FROM db.account UNION ALL SELECT * FROM db.account2", "SELECT * FROM db.trans UNION ALL SELECT * FROM db.trans2"]
```

And using my database connection I am trying to run all this queries in parallel instead of:

```
for query in queries:
  cursor.execute(query)
```

I'm trying to use multiprocessing library and my current code is:

```
import multiprocessing
def work():
   for query in queries:
      cursor.execute(query)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    _p = multiprocessing.Process(target=work)
    _p.start()
    _p.join()
```

However, it is taking the same time as the sequential mode... anyone knows how to run a parallel processing?

Thanks!

Comment: You might find that multithreading would be the more efficient approach over multiprocessing.

Answer (score 0):

It could be something like this:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    _processes = []
    for query in queries:
        _p = multiprocessing.Process(target=cursor.execute, args=(query,))
        _p.start()
        _processes.append(_p)

    for _p in _processes:
        _p.join()
```